# How to verify if a data source name is valid?

Tags: mysql, error-handling, rust

I am using [`OptsBuilder`](https://docs.rs/mysql/16.0.2/mysql/struct.OptsBuilder.html) passing a [data source name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_source_name) to create a connection pool:

```
let mut opts = mysql::OptsBuilder::from_opts(dsn);
opts.stmt_cache_size(0);
let pool = mysql::Pool::new_manual(1, 3, opts).expect("Could not connect to MySQL");
```

If I pass an invalid DSN, the code panics:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'URL ParseError { relative URL without a base }', ', /path/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/mysql-16.0.2/src/conn/opts.rs:827:25
```

How can I handle the error or verify in advance to prevent panicking?

Comment: Just to be sure: that's `Opts::from` that panics?

Comment: I don't know this lib, but I'd try to create an `Opts` with [`from_url`](https://docs.rs/mysql/16.0.2/mysql/struct.Opts.html#method.from_url) to be sure that `Into<Opts>` wont panic

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios is right, [from_opts](https://docs.rs/mysql_async/0.19.1/src/mysql_async/opts.rs.html#713) is already using `from_url` with `unwrap()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the `Opts` with [`from_url`](https://docs.rs/mysql/16.0.2/mysql/struct.Opts.html#method.from_url), so that you are sure that it won't fail after that:

```
let opts = match Opts::from_url(dsn) {
    Ok(opts) => opts,
    Err(e) => panic!(),// manage error
};
let mut opts = mysql::OptsBuilder::from_opts(opts);
opts.stmt_cache_size(0);
let pool = mysql::Pool::new_manual(1, 3, opts).expect("Could not connect to MySQL");
```

Comment: The dev team should implement [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) instead of `From`.

Comment: thanks, how good/bad is to use `Opts::from_url(dsn).unwrap_or_else(|e| { //handle erro});`

Comment: @nbari That's much idiomatic